# Ant Copy task with Path instead of FileSet

Tags: ant, path, copy

I'm using Ant 1.7, want to copy files from different paths (they have no relationship, so i cannot use the *include* selector to filter them out of their root directory). I try to use the `<path>` inside the `<copy>` instead of `<fileset>`, because with `<path>` i can specify multi paths which is in `<fileset>` not possible. My ant script looks like this, but it doesn't work.

```
<target name="copytest">
    <!-- copy all files in test1 and test2 into test3 -->
    <copy todir="E:/test3">
        <path>
            <pathelement path="C:/test1;D:/test2"></pathelement>
        </path>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Anybody has idea about how to use the `<path>` inside `<copy>`? Or maybe anybody has the advise about how to copy files from different source without selector?

Btw, i don't want to hard code the source directories, they will be read from a propertiy file, so writing multi `<fileset>` inside `<copy>` should not be considered.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this even work, the copy task started allowing the path element since version 1.7.0 but when i supply a path refid it copies nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<pathelement>` generally uses it's `path` attribute as a reference to `classpath` or some other predefined location, if you want to give specific file locations *outside of the classpath* try with `location` attribute

```
<pathelement location="D:\lib\helper.jar"/>
```

> The location attribute specifies a single file or directory relative
>   to the project's base directory (or an absolute filename), while the
>   path attribute accepts colon- or semicolon-separated lists of
>   locations. The path attribute is intended to be used with predefined
>   paths - in any other case, multiple elements with location attributes
>   should be preferred.

Comment: thanks for your explain, but i still don't find way out. The source directories are specified by user, which should be wroten in a property file. As you said, It doesn't work with location. And I don't want user to change the build.xml and add fileset by themself.

Comment: oh i missed that part, i thought you wanted to use *unrelated paths* instead of fileset, hence my answer. to read from a properties file, you would need to extract it as a `propertyset` and use that in the `location`. I dont have a working example

Answer (score 5):

This only works if the `flatten` attribute is set to `true`:

```
<copy todir="E:/test3" flatten="true">
    <path>
        <pathelement path="C:/test1;D:/test2"></pathelement>
    </path>
</copy>
```

This is documented in the `Examples` section of the [Ant Copy task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem

A bit more complicated that we need to add a specified pattern set to each fileset converted from path

For example, this is the incoming data

```
<path id="myDirList" path="C:/test1;D:/test2" />
<patternset id="myPatterns" includes="*.html, *.css, etc, " />
```

We wrote a script to solve this problem

```
<resources id="myFilesetGroup">
    <!-- mulitiple filesets to be generated here 
    <fileset dir="... dir1, dir2 ...">
        <patternset refid="myPatterns"/>
    </fileset>
    -->
</resources>
<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    (function () {
        var resources = project.getReference("myFilesetGroup");
        var sourceDirs = project.getReference("myDirList").list();
        var patterRef = new Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.types.Reference(project, "myPatterns");
        for (var i = 0; i < sourceDirs.length; i++) {
            var fileSet = project.createDataType("fileset");
            fileSet.dir = new java.io.File(sourceDirs[i]);
            fileSet.createPatternSet().refid = patterRef;
            resources.add(fileSet);
        }
    })();
]]></script>
```

now you can use this resources in you copy task

```
<!-- copy all files in test1 and test2 into test3 -->
<copy todir="E:/test3">
    <resources refid="myFilesetGroup">
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<copy
  includeemptydirs="true"
  failonerror="true" 
  overwrite="true"
  todir="${env.dist}/${for.env}/lib"
  **verbose="true"
  flatten="true"
>
  <path refid="classpath" />**
</copy>
```

Where classpath is reference of path used for pathelement.

Answer (score -1):

```
I tried this and works fine

<fileset file="${jackson.jaxrs.lib}"/>
```